# Edit Client-Side Aspxgridview objectdatasource that is in memory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, crud, aspxgridview

I am using VS 2013.  I am trying to create a "work order".  Currently, the user selects the items from an Inventory grid.  Then they click a button "View Selection" and the next page opens with the selected items which are in an Aspxgridview.  Here, the user should enter the quantity for each item.  How do I save the edits?

**ViewWorkOrder.aspx/Aspxgridview:**

```
 <dx:ASPxCallbackPanel runat="server" ID="ASPxCallbackPanelList" ClientInstanceName="CallbackPanelList" ClientSideEvents-EndCallback="OnEndCallback" EnableTheming="False">
                    <ClientSideEvents EndCallback="OnEndCallback"></ClientSideEvents>
                    <PanelCollection>
                        <dx:PanelContent>
    <dx:ASPxButton ID="ASPxButtonRequestItems" runat="server" EnableTheming="True" Text="Request Items" Theme="Office2003Olive" >
     </dx:ASPxButton>  

  <dx:ASPxGridView ID="GridViewWorkOrder"  ClientInstanceName="GridViewWorkOrder" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="InventoryDataSource" EnableTheming="True" Theme="Office2003Olive" KeyFieldName="Item_ID">

      <Columns>
           <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Item_ID" VisibleIndex="7" Visible="False" Width="0px">
               <Settings AllowAutoFilter="False" AllowGroup="False" AllowSort="False" />
          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Order_ID" VisibleIndex="8" Visible="False">
          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="User_ID" VisibleIndex="9" Visible="False">
          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataDateColumn FieldName="Date_Of_Order" VisibleIndex="1" Caption="Date" ReadOnly="True">
          </dx:GridViewDataDateColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Warehouse" VisibleIndex="6" Caption="WH" ReadOnly="True">
          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Department_Selected" VisibleIndex="10" Visible="False">
          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Equipment_Selected" VisibleIndex="11" Visible="False">
          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Item_Selected" VisibleIndex="4" Caption="Item#" ReadOnly="True">
          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn  FieldName="Quantity_Of_Order" VisibleIndex="2" Caption="Enter QTY" Width="5px" >
              <FilterCellStyle Wrap="True">
              </FilterCellStyle>
              <HeaderStyle Wrap="True" />
              <CellStyle BackColor="#CCFF99">
              </CellStyle>

          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Cost_Of_Item" VisibleIndex="3" Caption="Cost" ReadOnly="True">
              <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString="{0:c}">
              </PropertiesTextEdit>
          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
          <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Item" FieldName="Item_Description" ShowInCustomizationForm="True" VisibleIndex="5" ReadOnly="True">
          </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
      </Columns>        

      <SettingsBehavior AllowFocusedRow="True" />
      <SettingsEditing Mode="Batch">
      </SettingsEditing>
      <Settings ShowFooter="True" />
      <SettingsDataSecurity AllowDelete="False" AllowEdit="True" AllowInsert="False" />
  </dx:ASPxGridView>    


    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="InventoryDataSource" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetCheckBoxInventoryItem" TypeName="GetGridData" > 
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="User_ID" Type="Int64" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>

                </dx:PanelContent>
                </PanelCollection>           
            </dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>
```

There is no code behind other than a page load event that has nothing to do with the grid at this point.

There is no updatemethod set up. This is why I'm getting the error. (see pic, it is the topmost pic.) That's where I need help...
**Here is the code that populates the ObjectDataSource:**

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.HttpContext
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Web.HttpApplication

Public Module GetGridData

    Dim _FilteredInventoryList As New List(Of Inventory)


    Public Function GetCheckBoxInventoryItem(User_ID As Long) As List(Of OrderItem)

        Dim ItemList As Object = Split(mUser.SelectedInventoryCheckBox, "|")
        Dim _OrderItems As New List(Of OrderItem)
        _OrderItems.Clear()
        For Each r As String In ItemList
            Dim SelectedItem As String = Trim(r)
            _FilteredInventoryList = mInventorys.FindAll(Function(x) Trim(x.ID_Number) = SelectedItem)
            Dim _OrderItem As OrderItem
            For Each p In _FilteredInventoryList
                _OrderItem = New OrderItem
                With _OrderItem
                    .Item_ID = p.ID_Number
                    .Item_Selected = p.Item_Number
                    .Item_Description = p.Item_Description
                    .Cost_Of_Item = p.Current_Cost
                    .Quantity_Of_Order = Nothing
                    .Date_Of_Order = Now
                    .Warehouse = p.Warehouse_Location

                End With
                _OrderItems.Add(_OrderItem)
            Next
        Next
        GetCheckBoxInventoryItem = _OrderItems
    End Function
```

I don't need to update the actual database.  I just mainly want to save it and then click on the "Request Items" button and it will email order to a warehouse.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Snapshots]

Comment: Can anyone help with this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with VB. So I'll try my best here.

**First:**
 - You need to create an **Update** method in **GetGridData** class;

```
Public Function UpdateWorkOrder(pUser_id as long, pQuantity_Of_Order as decimal)
{
    /* UPDATE on database WorkOrder code */
}
```

**Second:**
 - Go on **asp:ObjectDataSource ID="InventoryDataSource"** and set the UpdateMethod as the method created above;

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource
    ID="InventoryDataSource" runat="server"
    TypeName="GetGridData"
    SelectMethod="GetCheckBoxInventoryItem" 
    UpdateMethod="UpdateWorkOrder"> 
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="User_ID" Type="Int64" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="User_ID" Type="Int64" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Quantity_Of_Order" Type="Decimal" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

If the grid already has an update button on the column that the user is editing, you do not need to do anything else